# 2D array acting strange

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a game of life in Ruby, and I have this code so far:

```
class Board
  def initialize(size)
    @board = [["-"] * size] * size
    @board[2][2] = "#"
  end
  def to_s
    @board.map{|r| 
      r.map{|i| print (i ? i.to_s : " ") + " "}
      puts
    }
  end
end

puts Board.new(5)
```

I would expect the result to be this:

```
- - - - - 
- - - - - 
- - # - - 
- - - - - 
- - - - -
```

But instead it is showing this:

```
- - # - - 
- - # - - 
- - # - - 
- - # - - 
- - # - -
```

I have no idea why, and I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the answer. I should have been using

```
@board = Array.new(size) { Array.new(size, "-") }
```

Instead of

```
@board = [["-"] * size] * size
```